# Converting data with whitespace into a dataframe

Tags: r

[image]

Converted this data from a pdf to a .csv file.

Since it had a lot of whitespace between columns, that tabula had a problem recognizing, I'm left with these 6 columns merged into one.

I was wondering if there's a way to convert them into 6 different columns, corresponding to the values in the rows.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **tidyr**, a package that can help exactly with these problems.
First, install and load tidyr.

```
install.packages("tidyverse") # a bunch of helpful packages including tidyr
install.packages("tidyr") # or you can just install tidyr
library(tidyr) # load tidyr
```

From the looks of it, the code you're looking for is:

```
separate(dataset, 1994_1995_1996_1997_1998_1999, sep = " ", into = c("1994", "1995", "1996", "1997", "1998", "1999")
```

`separate()` separates columns based on a separator (in this case, whitespace, corresponding to the `sep = " "` argument.

Comment: Thanks so much! This was wonderful. New to the community so I'm sorry if my question wasn't very clear/up to community standards!

Comment: I'm so glad I could help! I swear to you I learned that yesterday, so I was more than happy to help. Your question was excellent. Take care :)